# How to pass second parameter to function while using the map function of purrr package in R

Tags: r, purrr

Apologies for what might be a very simple question.

I am new to using the purrr package in R and I'm struggling with trying to pass a second parameter to a function.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

my_function <- function(x, y = 2) {
  z = x + y
  return(z)
}

my_df_2 <- my_df %>%
  mutate(new_col = map_dbl(.x = old_col, .f = my_function))
```

This works and most often I don't need to change the value of y, but if I had to pass a different value for y (say y = 3) through the mutate & map combination, what is the syntax for it?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The other idea is to use the following syntax.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# The function
my_function <- function(x, y = 2) {
  z = x + y
  return(z)
}

# Example data frame
my_df <- data_frame(old_col = 1:5)

# Apply the function   
my_df_2 <- my_df %>%
  mutate(new_col = map_dbl(old_col, ~my_function(.x, y = 3)))

my_df_2
# # A tibble: 5 x 2
# old_col new_col
#     <int>   <dbl>
# 1       1      4.
# 2       2      5.
# 3       3      6.
# 4       4      7.
# 5       5      8.
```

Comment: what is the purpose of ~ here?

Comment: Late answer but in case anyone else is wondering - within the context of [purrr](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/) functions `~` is shorthand for creating an inline anonymous function. See [this explanation](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functionals.html#purrr-shortcuts) from Advanced R for more info

Answer (score 5):

I think all you need to do is modify `map_dbl` like so:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- data.frame(a = c(2, 3, 4, 5.5))

my_function <- function(x, y = 2) {
  z = x + y
  return(z)
}

df %>%
  mutate(new_col = map_dbl(.x = a, y = 3, .f = my_function))
```

> ```
>     a new_col
> 1 2.0     5.0
> 2 3.0     6.0
> 3 4.0     7.0
> 4 5.5     8.5
> ```

Comment: I don't see why it was necessary to remove the default value of the `y` argument in `my_function`? The rest of the answer is good.

Comment: Your right, it works either way. If OP usually has 2 as the default value (which seems to be the case) I should probably modify my answer as so. I just like to keep the function as minimal as possible.

Comment: Np, happy to help @user1823293